# How to deal with a function with an exists on the right side?

Tags: coq

I am not sure whether I am using the right words in the question title, so here is the code:

```
Lemma In_map_iff :
  forall (A B : Type) (f : A -> B) (l : list A) (y : B),
    In y (map f l) <->
    exists x, f x = y /\ In x l.
Proof.
  intros A B f l y.
  split.
  - intros.
    induction l.
    + intros. inversion H.
    + exists x.
      simpl.
      simpl in H.
      destruct H.
      * split.
        { apply H. } 
        { left. reflexivity. }
      * split.
```

---

```
  A : Type
  B : Type
  f : A -> B
  x : A
  l : list A
  y : B
  H : In y (map f l)
  IHl : In y (map f l) -> exists x : A, f x = y /\ In x l
  ============================
  f x = y
```

Basically, there is not much to go on with this proof, I can only really use `induction` on `l` and after substituting for `x` in the goal I get the above form. If `IHl` had a forall instead of `exists` maybe I could substitute something there, but I am not sure at all what to do here.

I've been stuck on this one for a while now, but unlike the other problems where that has happened, I could not find the solution online for this one. This is a problem as I am going through the book on my own, so have nobody to ask except in places like SO.

I'd appreciate a few hints. Thank you.

---

```
Lemma In_map_iff :
  forall (A B : Type) (f : A -> B) (l : list A) (y : B),
    In y (map f l) <->
    exists x, f x = y /\ In x l.
Proof.
  intros A B f l y.
  split.
  - intros.
    induction l.
    + intros. inversion H.
    + simpl.
      simpl in H.
      destruct H.
      * exists x.
        split.
        { apply H. }
        { left. reflexivity. }
      * destruct IHl.
        -- apply H.
        -- exists x0.
           destruct H0.
           ++ split.
              ** apply H0.
              ** right. apply H1.
  - intros.
    inversion H.
    induction l.
    + intros.
      inversion H.
      inversion H1.
      inversion H3.
    + simpl.
      right.
      apply IHl.
      * inversion H.
        inversion H0.
        inversion H2.
        exists x.
        split.
        -- reflexivity.
        -- destruct H3.
```

---

```
  A : Type
  B : Type
  f : A -> B
  x0 : A
  l : list A
  y : B
  H : exists x : A, f x = y /\ In x (x0 :: l)
  x : A
  H0 : f x = y /\ In x (x0 :: l)
  IHl : (exists x : A, f x = y /\ In x l) ->
        f x = y /\ In x l -> In y (map f l)
  x1 : A
  H1 : f x1 = y /\ In x1 (x0 :: l)
  H2 : f x = y
  H3 : x0 = x
  H4 : f x = y
  ============================
  In x l
```

I managed to do one case, but am now stuck in the other. To be honest, since I've already spent 5 hours on a problem that should need like 15 minutes, I am starting to think that maybe I should consider genetic programming at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a proof that has the same structure as would have a pen-and-paper proof (at least the first `->` part). When you see `<tactic>...` it means `; intuition` (because of `Proof with intuition.` declaration), i.e. apply the `intuition` tactic to all the subgoals generated by `<tactic>`. `intuition` enables us not to do tedious logical deductions and can be replaced by a sequence of `apply` and `rewrite` tactics, utilizing some logical lemmas.

As @ejgallego pointed out the key here is that while proving you can `destruct` existential hypotheses and get inhabitants of some types out of them. Which is crucial when trying to prove existential goals.

```
Require Import Coq.Lists.List.

Lemma some_SF_lemma :
  forall (A B : Type) (f : A -> B) (l : list A) (y : B),
    In y (map f l) <->
    exists x, f x = y /\ In x l.
Proof with intuition.
  intros A B f l y. split; intro H.
  - (* -> *)
    induction l as [ | h l'].
    + (* l = [] *)
      contradiction.
    + (* l = h :: l' *)
      destruct H.
      * exists h...
      * destruct (IHl' H) as [x H'].
        exists x...
  - (* <- *)
    admit.
Admitted.
```

Comment: This looks quite nice. Is there any way to make Coq print out the exact steps it has taken? It is hard to understand like this as it just zooms past to the finish line in the second case. Based on the experience of previous problems where I get stuck, either I do not do the order of destructuring and generalization correctly or I miss some obvious rewrite, so the less I have to write things out by hand the less chance for error there is. So automating as much as possible should be the preferred style. But I do need to see under the hood if I am to learn anything.

Comment: I know there is the [Info](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/Reference-Manual011.html#hevea_command210) command, but I am not sure how to use it. Some pointers on that would be welcome.

Comment: (1) Off the top of my head I can come only with `Print In_map_iff.` after `Qed.`. That will print the proof term and with some experience you'll be able to read off the logical laws/lemmas used by `intuition`. Caveat: it can be pretty hard. (2) I've added some manual proofs as comments to clarify what could `...` do.

Comment: I see where I went wrong now. I tried destructing IHl myself before, but missed the two step rewrite needed to complete one of the branches and wrote off the avenue as impossible. Did not know about subst before. Why does the `intuition` require the lists from the standard library instead of the ones by me?

Comment: I had to import `List` since you didn't publish your definitions. Did you implement `In` as `Fixpoint` or `Inductive`?

Comment: Then your implementation should work without that import, unless it is missing some `Hint`s (`Hint Resolve` and/or `Hint Immediate`), which `intuition` might use (I'm not sure about that). You can check the hints stdlib uses [here](https://coq.inria.fr/library/Coq.Lists.List.html), "Facts about app" section and maybe some others.

Comment: By the way, I didn't know `In_map_iff` was an SF exercise. I shouldn't have published the whole solution, so I'm going to delete some part of it, so not to make it easy to copy-paste the solution for the students taking the course at a university.

Answer (score 2):

`H` can be true on two different ways, try `destruct H`. From that, the proof follows easily I think, but be careful on the order you destruct `H` and instantiate the existential thou.

Comment: I've updated as far as I could go this time. I am really not sure what the existential in `IHl` is supposed to be doing.

Comment: Try to think "logically" about the provenance of the existential witnesses. Indeed, it could be the case, if you follow the reasoning of the pen-and-paper proof, that you may need to instantiate your existential with the witness _obtained_ from destructing some other existential in your hypothesis.

Comment: I did manage to get through the first case somehow, but I am now stuck in the other one. To be honest, I need a better approach for this, I do not even care about theorem proving that much, nor have any idea how to prove this problem informally - all I wanted was to figure out how dependently typed programming works for languages like Idris and Fstar which are currently lacking in learning materials. I do know Coq has automation functions under the hood, but the thing they print out is super ugly. Has anybody thrown something like a genetic algorithm at this?

Comment: @MarkoGrdinic Besides nice official tutorials for Idris and F*, you can also find more in the following books. [Type-driven development with Idris](https://www.manning.com/books/type-driven-development-with-idris) by E. Brady (a very nice reading, beginners-oriented). Since Idris and Agda a somewhat similar [Verified Functional Programming in Agda](https://svn.divms.uiowa.edu/repos/clc/projects/agda/book/book.pdf) by A. Stump can fit the bill as well (it's free of charge). And A. Chlipala's [CDPT](http://adam.chlipala.net/cpdt/) shows some dependently-typed programming techniques in Coq.

Comment: @MarkoGrdinic oh! Indeed if you want to use a tool like Coq you should learn how to prove "on paper" the theorems first, otherwise, you are trying to catch a fly with a Hammer. If you really want to go down the route of automatic theorem proving, I'd recommend Why3 instead. Even with Why3, you will need to understand why you properties cannot be proved, so yeah, with the current status of tools I'd dare to say that they are hard to use unless you have a pretty good prior understanding on software verification.